# PICKIT 2 verification failed at memory address 0x0000

Tags: pic, pickit

I have been using a [DSPIC30f4011](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en010337) for two days but suddenly I am no longer able to program the chip again.

The message I am getting:

**Failed to verify at programming address 0x0000**  (when I click the Verify button).

**Failed to program at programming address 0x0000** (when I click the Write button).

**Successful** (when I click Read button).

**Successful** (when I click erase button).

I clicked on the erase button and tried to get rid of the error. But when I clicked read after erasing it, the first byte is still 0000 0000. Everything else is FFFF.

I am pretty sure the wiring and power supply is correct because when I put a new chip into the spot where the old chip was at, PICKIT 2 is able to program/verify it.

The pickit shows All protect for both old chip and new chip so it's not a problem.

Comment: If you can erase it then what is read? Also what voltage are you running

Comment: Also do you have the code protection set in the config?

Comment: @GradyPlayer The erase is not working. Every time read will return the same thing after the chip is erased. I am running at 4.7 V.  I never enable code protect. Another new chip is doing the same thing to me.

Comment: I was having the same thing yesterday with a 16f884, after pulling my LEDs out, and reprogramming once at 5v then unchecking erase before program I was able to reprogram... After reading that whole chip erase needs 5v

Comment: Yeah, I do have several LEDs connected to the chip when it is being programmed. But unplugging them doesn't solve the problem. Thanks though.

Comment: well unplugging the leds was only to allow me to bump the voltage to 5.0 from 3.3 without changing resistor values or burning them up.

Comment: What happens when you do a blank check after an erase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AVDD and AVSS must be connected.

Comment: Was this responsible for the issue you were having?

Comment: yes. At least for the chip I'm using, as soon as they are connected the issue is gone. page 12 of the datasheet: "This pin must be connected at all times."

Answer (score 3):

The device is probably faulty.

Comment: but I am able to read from it.

Comment: But you can't program it.

Comment: I concur that the device may be damaged or there is a problem with device power.

Answer (score 1):

If you attempt to erase a device and then perform a blank check on it and the blank check fails there’s a chance that the flash memory on the IC is bad. Flash memory based devices only have so many erase / write cycles that can be performed on them before they burn out.